# Python - Read image from a URL then use for face_recognition?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, urllib

I am trying to feed an image from URL to a [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) library that I'm using, but it does not seem to be working.

I have tried the suggestion here: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/442 but it did not work for me. I'm thinking that my problem is with the method that I'm using for fetching the image, and not the face_recognition library, that's why I decided to post the question here.

Bellow is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import face_recognition
import urllib.request

url = "https://carlofontanos.com/wp-content/themes/carlo-fontanos/img/carlofontanos.jpg"
img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img)

# Find all the faces in the image using the default HOG-based model.
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

for face_location in face_locations:

    # Print the location of each face in this image
    top, right, bottom, left = face_location
    print("A face is located at pixel location Top: {}, Left: {}, Bottom: {}, Right: {}".format(top, left, bottom, right))

    # You can access the actual face itself like this:
    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]
    pil_image = Image.fromarray(face_image)
    pil_image.show()
```

I'm getting the following response when running the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 83, in load_image_file
    im = PIL.Image.open(file)
  File "C:\Users\Carl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2643, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I think the problem is with the line `AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Image` to load it

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
image = face_recognition.load_image_file(response)
```

`urlopen()` gives object which has methods `read()`, `seek()` so it is treated as `file-like object`. And `load_image_file()` needs `filename` or `file-like object`

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.request.urlopen(url)` returns a http response and not an image file. i think you are supposed to download the image and give the path of the files as input to load_image_file().

Comment: I won't downvote this, but @furas's answer is actually working